# What are the classes in $SU(2)/T$ fixed by multiplication by any element in $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, quotient-spaces

Let $G = SU(2)$ and let $T $ be the subset of diagonal matrices in $G$.

I'm stuck trying to understand what the following set is:

$$ M= \lbrace [g] \in G/T\mid [tg]=[g], \forall t \in T\rbrace. $$

I just can think of the classes $[t]$, $t \in T$ .

Are there any other classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
The subset of diagonal matrices in $G=SU(2)$ forms a subgroup of $G$.
If
$$
G/T=\{Tg\,\mid\,g\in G\},
$$
then $M=G/T$.
If
$$
G/T=\{gT\,\mid\,g\in G\},
$$
then $M=\{[e],[a]\}$ with
$$
a=
\left(%
\begin{array}{rc}
  0 & 1 \\
  -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}%
\right).
$$